# Franck-Condon principle and shift of wavelength

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy

I was revisiting my notes for spectroscopy, and I came across the Franck-Condon-principle. I understand it well, but want to clear some doubts regarding this.

I know that the Franck-Condon-principle states that during an electronic transition from the ground state vibrational state (according to Boltzmann, the most populated), a transition happens, but not to the ground vibrational state of the electronically higher state, but to a vibrationally excited state of the electronically higher state, as seen here:

[image]

So, as seen by the excitation (highlighted in blue), the excited state of the electronically higher state decays through collision with other molecules to the ground vibrational state and fluorescences to a vibrationally excited state of the electronic ground state. That is the reason why the Emission spectrum is lower in energy than the absorption spectrum (Stokes shift):
[image]

For me there remains a doubt:
So basically for the transition to happen, the electronic energy difference needs to be overcome **plus** the vibrational difference, all by **one** photon that matches the energy difference as seen in picture 1. However, in statistical thermodynamics it is always assumed that electronic and vibrational transitions are uncoupled, so one photon should only ever excite an electronic transition, or a vibrational transition, but one photon can’t change both modes (electronic + vibrational) at the same time. Where did I think wrong?

Comment: No problem ! One photon can easily change both modes (electronic + vibration) at the same time. This is even what happens in nearly all photon absorptions in the visible or ultra-violet region.

Comment: Okay that makes sense then, but is the premise of statistical thermodynamics then wrong?

Comment: Wrong ? What sort of "premise of statistical thermodynamics" are you speaking of ?

Comment: The geometry  of the ground state and excited state are different so that transitions from any ground state vibrational level to any excited state one are allowed (supposing also spin allowed). The intensity of these vibronic transitions are determined by the wavefunction overlap which directly produces each FC factor. btw in the gas phase at low pressures there can be no collisions (during several excited state lifetimes) so that emission occurs from the initially excited level.

Comment: As @Maurice says, you are messing up your Statistical Thermodynamics.  When describing the population of the molecule in the ground state, it is usually assumed that the different molecular degrees of freedom are uncoupled so the electronic, vibrational, rotational and translational molecular degrees of freedom can be treated separately. Normally, the energy of the excited electronic excited electronic states is much higher than that of the ground state, in a good approximation the upper state is empty, and this state can only be accessed through photon absorption.

Comment: The absorption intensity is related to the initial population of the initial state, so there is no absorption from an empty state.
However, the absorption intensity also depends on the transition probability which depends on the wave functions of the excited state and the ground state and their transition moment. There is no need for Statistical Thermodynamics here.

Comment: A bit of a necro here, but I think one key thing missing in these comments is that the vibrational and electronic degrees of freedom being decoupled (approximately) does not mean that they are separate states. The states of the system would have to specify all of the energetic contributions, no matter how you actually found them. So transitioning between different electronic and vibrational levels simultaneously is not only allowed, it is what you would expect to happen by default.